# Premake doesn't picking up dependencies

Tags: premake

Recently I've changed from CMake to Premake (v5.0.0-alpha8) and I'm not quite sure how to achieve the the following in Premake.

I want to include some dependencies so in CMake I can do something like this:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    ${YALLA_ABS_PLATFORM}
    ${YALLA_LIBRARY})
```

The above will add the paths of these libraries (dir) to "Additional Include Directories" in the compiler and it will also add an entry (lib) to "Additional Dependencies" in the linker so I don't need to do anything special beyond calling `target_link_libraries`.

So I expected that when I'm doing something like this in Premake:

```
links {
    YALLA_LIBRARY
}
```

I'd get the same result but I don't.

I also tried to use the `libdirs` but it doesn't really *work*, I mean I can't see the library directory and its subdirectories passed to the compiler as "Additional Include Directories" (/I) or Yalla.Library.lib passed to the the linker as "Additional Dependencies".

**Here is the directory structure I use:**

```
.
|-- src
|   |-- launcher
|   |-- library
|   |   `-- utils
|   `-- platform
|       |-- abstract
|       `-- win32
`-- tests
    `-- platform
        `-- win32
```

The **library** dir is defined in Premake as follow:

```
project(YALLA_LIBRARY)
    kind "SharedLib"

    files {
        "utils/string-converter.hpp",
        "utils/string-converter.cpp",
        "defines.hpp"
    }
```

The **platform** dir is defined in Premake as follow:

```
project(YALLA_PLATFORM)
    kind "SharedLib"
    includedirs "abstract"

    links {
        YALLA_LIBRARY
    }

    if os.get() == "windows" then
        include     "win32"
    else
        return -- OS NOT SUPPORTED
    end
```

The **win32** dir is defined in Premake as follow:

```
files {
    "event-loop.cpp",
    "win32-exception.cpp",
    "win32-exception.hpp",
    "win32-window.cpp",
    "win32-window.hpp",
    "window.cpp"
}
```

And finally at the **root** dir I have the following Premake file:

```
PROJECT_NAME = "Yalla"

-- Sets global constants that represents the projects' names
YALLA_LAUNCHER = PROJECT_NAME .. ".Launcher"
YALLA_LIBRARY = PROJECT_NAME .. ".Library"
YALLA_ABS_PLATFORM = PROJECT_NAME .. ".AbstractPlatform"
YALLA_PLATFORM = PROJECT_NAME .. ".Platform"

workspace(PROJECT_NAME)
    configurations  { "Release", "Debug" }
    flags           { "Unicode" }

    startproject    ( YALLA_LAUNCHER )
    location        ( "../lua_build" )

    include         "src/launcher"
    include         "src/library"
    include         "src/platform"
```

I'm probably misunderstanding how Premake works due to lack of experience with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating a new global function and named it `includedeps`.

```
function includedeps(workspace, ...) 
    local workspace = premake.global.getWorkspace(workspace)

    local args = { ... }
    local args_count = select("#", ...)
    local func = select(args_count, ...)

    if type(func) == "function" then
        args_count = args_count - 1
        args = table.remove(args, args_count)
    else
        func = nil
    end

    for i = 1, args_count do
        local projectName = select(i, ...)
        local project = premake.workspace.findproject(workspace, projectName)
        if project then
            local topIncludeDir, dirs = path.getdirectory(project.script)
            if func then 
                dirs = func(topIncludeDir)
            else
                dirs = os.matchdirs(topIncludeDir .. "/**")
                table.insert(dirs, topIncludeDir)
            end
            includedirs(dirs)
            if premake.project.iscpp(project) then
                libdirs(dirs)    
            end
            links(args)
        else
            error(string.format("project '%s' does not exist.", projectName), 3)
        end
    end
end
```

**Usage:**

```
includedeps(PROJECT_NAME, YALLA_LIBRARY)
```

or

```
includedeps(PROJECT_NAME, YALLA_PLATFORM, function(topIncludeDir)
            return { path.join(topIncludeDir, "win32") }
        end)
```

**Update:**

For this to work *properly* you need to make sure that when you `include` the dependencies they are included by their dependency order and not by the order of the directory structure.

So for example if I have the following dependency graph `launcher --> platform --> library` then I'll have to `include` them in the following order.

```
include         "src/library"
include         "src/platform"
include         "src/launcher"
```

As opposed to the directory structure that in my case is as follow:

```
src/launcher
src/library
src/platform
```

If you will include them by their directory structure it will fail and tell you that "The project 'Yalla.Platform' does not exist."